# Isolation forest - grouped by

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, outlier

I'm trying to use isolation forest algorithm for outliers detection.
Data has 2 columns: `id` and `REV`. Below code gives me ungrouped result.
Could you pls advise how to get result grouped by first column (`id`)?

```
data= pd.read_excel (my_path)
outliers_fraction=0.1
scaler = StandardScaler()
np_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
model =IsolationForest(contamination=outliers_fraction)
model.fit(data)
data['anomaly'] = pd.Series(model.predict(data))
print(data)
```

I have 2 columns: `id` and `REV`. I added a picture of what I expect to see as the final result:

[image]

---

Tried to use function, but have half of data NaN. Any thoughts please?

```
def groupreg(g):
        outliers_fraction = 0.1
        # train isolation forest
        model = IsolationForest(contamination=outliers_fraction)
        model.fit(g)
        g['anomalyX'] = pd.Series(model.predict(g))
        return g

    df1=data2.groupby('id').apply(groupreg)
    print(df1)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and sample out that you are expecting and what it is coming out to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution if somebody will need it someday

```
def groupreg(df):
    a=df[['EUR']].values
    # train isolation forest
    model = IsolationForest()
    model.fit(a)
    return pd.Series(model.predict(a))

result=df.groupby('id').apply(groupreg)
#print(result)

#print(isolationforest(data2))
df['outlier1'] = result.tolist()
print(df)
```